# How to properly fork() a process

Tags: c, fork, execvp

I'm trying to understand how to properly used [fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) and [execvp()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) to execute a command. So far I have the following code:

When I run `./test vim myFile.c` it correctly opens `myFile.c` but I get strange behavior. It seems as though there are two processes running because whenever I enter anything it seems to happen twice. Why is this?

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
   int fdin, pid, w, status; 
   fdin = 0;                                                                   
   if ((pid = fork()) < 0)                                                     
       errorExit (EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                                                              
   execvp(argv[0],argv);  

   do {
      w = waitpid(cpid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
      if (w == -1) {
          perror("waitpid");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

     if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
          printf("exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
      } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
          printf("killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
      } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
          printf("stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
      } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
          printf("continued\n");
      }
  } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status))
}
```

Comment: `execvp(argv[0], argv)` should just keep executing the same program (`test`, not `vim`!) over and over again, since you call it for both the parent and child of `fork()`...

Comment: after a fork() the code needs to differentiate between parent and child.  Your code makes no differentation so both the parent and the child are running the code.  So both the parent and the child are performing the execvp() function.  to differentiate, check the returned pid value, if ==0 then in child, else in parent.  have the parent (pid not - 0) skip around the execvp call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call fork(), you create two almost completely identical processes, the parent process and the child process. The only difference between these two processes is the return value of fork(), which returns 0 to the child process and the pid of the child to the parent.

Hence, assuming fork succeeded, fork will return a nonnegative integer to both the parent and child process in line 4. Then, both the parent and child process will execute line 6, the execvp, and hence, you end up with two different processes running your vim myFile.c, causing all the problems you described.

The standard idiom is something like:

```
if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    // Handle fork error
}
else if (pid == 0) {
    // Child process
    execvp(...);
}
else {
    // Parent process
    w = waitpid(pid, ...);
}
```

Since the return value for fork is 0 for the child, after fork succeeds, the test (pid == 0) will be true for the child, so execvp will be called.

For the parent, fork returns the pid of the child, so the check (pid == 0), which still get executed, is false, so the else condition is executed, causing the parent to wait for the child.

Comment: Do I need the do while loop?

Comment: No, you don't need the while loop. By default, waitpid will cause the parent to sleep until the child exits. See http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid for example.

Comment: if you scroll to the bottom of the man page you'll see that their example code includes a while loop. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

Both parent and child in your program get `execvp()`:

```
if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    errorExit (EXIT_FAILURE);
execvp(argv[0],argv);
```

You should check, if you are in parent with `pid != 0`, and if you are in child otherwise.

Comment: Do I need the do while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the return value of fork, after a successful fork you will have two running processes at the same position in your program. The child process will get a return value of 0, the parent will get a return value which is the pid of the child. Most likely you want to do different things in the child process and the parent process.

You might also want to think again about how execvp is called. Do you really want to give "./test" as the first argument to execvp?